# How to execute a file in windows using NodeJS?

Tags: windows, node.js, windows-server-2012

I installed Nodejs and I'm using it for the first time.  The API is a bit too generic.  The first example does not explain how to specify a file path.  I setup the testFile.js with the code:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':     
'text/plain'});
  response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8124);

console.log('Server running at     
http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

I verified node.js is correctly installed by typing `"node <enter> 1 + 1"` and got a response of "2".  Then I tried:

```
>node "C:\path\testNode.js"
```

This returns `...` which is no different than passing an incorrect file

`>node "C:\INCORRECTPATH\testNode.js"`

Then I tried dropping the parenthesis, still no work.  Also tried doing a change directory before running "node" command.  Guess what!  Still no worky.  The error `...` is super useful, but I just dunno how to fix it..?

What's the syntax?

Comment: Go to the directory with the file and just type `node testNode.js`

Comment: @adeneo Can you be more specific?  I already tried something to that effect `Also tried doing a change directory before running "node" command. Guess what! Still no worky`

Comment: Not sure I can be more specific, open a DOS window, go to the directory with the file, usually using something like `cd /mydirectory` and then just run node `testNode.js`

Comment: @adeneo - In that case, as I explained in the OP I already did that.

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE

`<AnticlimacticConclusion>`
Restarting the computer corrected the problem.
`</AnticlimacticConclusion>`

So node.js *did install*.  And it even gave results (remember in the OP 1 + 1 returns 2).  But, the PATH remained jacked up for whatever reason.   (Yes I tried a new instance of cmd).

(The rest of this post is **old information** for reference only)

**What did not work**

The commands did not function when I went to the command prompt via:

`start > run > cmd > node C:\path\testNode.js`

It also did not function with a shortcut I had in my start menu to an admin mode version of cmd which links to:

`%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat""`

**What worked**

I ran a search on my PC and found a program entitled "Node.js command prompt".  The shortcut on my machine pointed to:

`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat"`

When I run node commands with this batch file pre-loaded then everything works out.  E.G.

`> node C:\path\testNode.js`

returns `Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/`.  A picture says 1000 words.  Note the first line.
[image]

In other words, it appears this batch file is required.

Comment: A batch file shouldn't be required.  If you installed node using the MSI, it should have added node to your PATH.  You should be able to just type `node` in a regular command prompt.

Comment: @josh3736 - Ya, I would think so too.  I installed the MSI x64 from http://nodejs.org/download/.  It just ain't working out that way.

Comment: Yep, sometimes you have to reboot to completely affect a change to PATH.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're executing the node command inside a node repl.

This would happen if you are working in the window that pops up when you click a "Node.js" icon in your start menu.

To execute it in the way you've tried, run it from a normal command prompt. i.e. hit windows-r, type cmd, press return, or find Command Prompt in your start menu.

You can also run an external node script from inside the node repl by requiring it.

```
 require("C:\\path\\testNode.js")
```

This will only work the first time as it is cached for subsequent require calls.